# Where is implementation of 'hasSystemFeature()' method?

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I'd like to see implementation of 'hasSystemFeature()' method.
Please inform me where the implementation is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual implementation calls through to the package manager service. Its implementation of `hasSystemFeature()` is at [services/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java) in the Android base platform frameworks repository.

Comment: If I press "cmd+B" I land here: 
public abstract boolean hasSystemFeature(String name);
If I "Go To Implementation(s)" i land:
@Override public boolean hasSystemFeature(String name) {     throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
How can I open PackageManagerService.java directly from "getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(...);"
in Android Studio?